# Ruby 99% ++ CPU Usage on Mac

Tags: ruby, macos, visual-studio

I have a problem in running Ruby in my Mac machine. I've been google for a while but not found satisfying answer, so i decided to ask myself.

I run some simple ruby code using Visual Studio Code and i see something odd. The ruby process is taking 99%++ CPU usage.

[image]

As you can see, it taking 99% CPU usage just for a single simple code. It will still running until i force quit the service and sometimes there is not just one process.

this is the code that i run:

```
range1 = 1..5
something = 3
something.to_s
print something
```

this is the... running files, memory location things (i don't know what it called) in the Ruby service:

```
cwd
/
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/libruby.2.5.0.dylib
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/enc/encdb.bundle
txt
/usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.1.2_1/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/stringio.bundle
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/etc.bundle
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/pathname.bundle
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/openssl.bundle
txt
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.0g_1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
txt
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.0g_1/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/digest.bundle
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/io/nonblock.bundle
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/zlib.bundle
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/digest/sha1.bundle
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/socket.bundle
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/io/wait.bundle
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/enc/windows_31j.bundle
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/json/ext/parser.bundle
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/json/ext/generator.bundle
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/readline.bundle
txt
/usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.3_1/lib/libreadline.7.0.dylib
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/strscan.bundle
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/date_core.bundle
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/cgi/escape.bundle
txt
/Users/konzaho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/digest/md5.bundle
txt
/usr/lib/dyld
txt
/private/var/db/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64h
0
->0x369452a54d0e4c31
1
->0x369452a54d0e4911
2
->0x369452a54d0e38a9
3
->0x369452a54b81a3e9
4
->0x369452a54b81b769
5
->0x369452a54b81a569
6
->0x369452a54d0e38a9
7
->0x369452a54b81bb29
8
[ctl com.apple.netsrc id 9 unit 27]
9
->0x369452a54d0e5271
10
localhost:59277
11
localhost:59277
12
->0x369452a54b81a0e9
13
->0x369452a54b81a4a9
14
localhost:59277->localhost:59285
15
localhost:59277->localhost:59286
16
localhost:59277->localhost:59287
24
->0x369452a5536d6789
25
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar
27
/Users/konzaho/Devs/ruby/bookTwo.rb
```

Is it normal for Ruby to taking this much of CPU power just to run a simple code?
Yes, of course i can just instantly force quit the process, but it kind of annoying to do it every time you close the editor and it heated up my machine too.

EDIT:
I run this code in the Visual Code's terminal and the

> bookTwo.rb

i exactly the same code as I mention above. Now I run the code in the Mac's terminal but it does not have the problem as I run in the VS Code terminal.

Comment: No, that is not normal. But from the information you've given I can not determine what would be the issue. Your ruby code, at least what you provided, can not cause this issue on its own. You need to provide some more information on how you execute this piece of code.

Comment: Are you running the Ruby code from within Visual Studio? It might be doing something weird when it runs your script. Do you get the same issue when running it from the terminal with just `ruby bookTwo.rb`?

Comment: @SanderSaelmans yes, i just use the exact same code as i put here to take the screenshoot and the running files, memory thing.

Sorry i forgot to mention, i run this program in the Visual Studio terminal, i though it will be the same as a Mac build-in terminal

Comment: Why is that code running for 39+ seconds? It should print 3 and exit.

Comment: @Max yes, i run the code in Visual Code. I run the code several times in Mac's terminal but it seem the process does not appear as high as I run in the Visual Code's terminal, it even just sitting in around 0%.

maybe there is something wrong with the Visual Code terminal?

Comment: @StefanPochmann that 99% is relative to one core (so it can be above 100%), whereas 86% refers to all cores (cannot be above 100%). It's probably an 8-core machine (or 4 with hyperthreading).

Comment: @Stefan thank you for the answer.

For your question, may I know where do you know the code is running for 39+ seconds? And you are right, the code should just print 3 and then exit

EDIT: nevermind, i just realized its in my screenshoot.

Comment: @F.Rhamdani "CPU Time" says 39.28 – maybe you are looking at the wrong process?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're confirming that the slowness only happens in the Visual Code terminal, not a general terminal. So my guess is that it has nothing to do with Ruby, but something about how Visual Code manages the processes launched by its terminal.

Comment: @Stefan I don't think so, because the process is calling my ruby file according to the process activity log i provide above.

Comment: Have you restarted your computer, and ran the same code from the terminal monitoring the CPU usage? Not visual studio, I would eliminate that program in the meantime until you solve this problem. I have just recently began programming in c# on my Mac using visual studio and it constantly has bugs in the IDE

Comment: If you just google "visual studio high cpu on Mac" you may note you are not the only one with this problem and it is not limited to ruby code

Comment: Hey, mate, got same problem, while using RubyMine - Ive used yarn to install material-design-icons and then BOOM, 99.7% CPU usage from 'ruby'. I guess RubyMine is trying to index all this icons (around 89k files)

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `top -o ppid` in a Terminal window
2. Locate the `PPID` for most CPU-intensive process (top of list)
3. Run `kill -9 <INSERT_PPID_HERE>`